# Источник энтропии в компьютере?

Tags: случайные-числа

как или откуда программно можно получить случайные велечины, данные, значения в пк,
без использования спец устройств или доп. оборудования?

Comment: @Вячеслав1101 сформулируйте поконкретнее - с чем связан этот вопрос?  Какие случайные величины вы хотите получить? О каком спецоборудовании идет речь?

Comment: @Вячеслав1101 Конкретика, побольше конкретики. Тут не форум экстрасенсов )

Comment: [/dev/random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random)

Answer (score 2):

Время(мили секунды)
Серийный номер диска (или чего-то еще что придет в голову)
Можно сохранять в случайные величины время, которое пользователь тратит на нажатие клавиш
Одним словом: есть где разбежаться.
Зависит по большей мере от среды разработки вашего программного продукта.